# How to improve speed of export to CSV and XLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby model that has an **export** method

```
class InfoVoucher < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  default_scope { order('voucher_created_at DESC') }

  def attributes
    instance_values
  end

  def self.export(data, options = {})
    column_names = ["..","..","..","..",..]
    exported_col_names = ["Solicitud", "Inicio", "Final", "Duracion", "Pasajero", "Unidades", "Recargo", "Propina", "Costo", "Centro de costo", "Origen", "Destino",  "Proyecto", "Conductor", "Placas"]

    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << exported_col_names

      data.each do |row_export|
        csv << row_export.attributes['attributes'].values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works but with very large files or queries the export is taking to long

At first I thought that this was because the query was run again (once for the HTML render and then again for the export) but as it turns out, avoiding running the query again for the export did not improve the speed much - [How to reuse the query result for faster export to csv and xls without using global or session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281978/how-to-reuse-the-query-result-for-faster-export-to-csv-and-xls-without-using-glo/27300813#27300813)

In some languages the concatenation is a very expensive task specially that **csv** variable is being concatenated with the contents of the exported whole file, record by record

**data** is the result of an model that inherits from ActiveRecord after a where method with filters

```
@filters = {}
@filters['email_enterprise'] = session[:enterprise_email] ;

 # Add the selected filters
if (params[:f_passenger].to_s != '')
  @filters['id_passenger'] = params[:f_passenger] ;
end
if (session[:role] == 2)
  @filters['cost_center'] = session[:cc_name]
end

# Apply the filters and store them in the MemoryCache to make them available when exporting
@last_consult = InfoVoucher.where(@filters)
```

How can I improve this to make it as efficient as possible

Comment: Tried using `pluck` to retrieve the attributes instead of building an AR object? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: @avlazarov I never heard of it, I am very new and how can It help me to improve speed ? I see that it allows filters, and queries but the results that I need to export are already filter and ready in the `data` variable

Comment: What is `data` exactly?

Comment: @Deefour I have updated the question to explain what data is

Comment: @avlazarov I am very new to Ruby. In which line of code is a new AR object being created ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Keeping Memory Low

When working with a huge data set, try to create as few objects as possible and pull as little as necessary from the database. You're loading every column from the `info_vouchers` table into individual `InfoVoucher` classes in `@last_consult`. This is unnecessary.

One thing you can do is  what @avlazarov suggested; use [`#pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to go from the database directly into a nested array of *just* the columns you're interested in.

```
useful_data = InfoVoucher.where(@filters).pluck(*column_names)
```

#### Queue Long Running Tasks

You should always queue tasks like this to be handled later by a worker. [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) are popular choices.

The benefit of this is the user's request for the export will be performant, notifying them immediately that their request has been queued. Email them the report when it's done.

Comment: This functionality first renders the result in HTML and then allows it to be exported as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281978/how-to-reuse-the-query-result-for-faster-export-to-csv-and-xls-without-using-glo/27300813#27300813